# AS3 with mysql connection with sockets or PHP?

Tags: mysql, database, flash, actionscript-3, sockets

So, we want to move out from Air (Adobe stopping support and really bad implementation for the sqlite api, among other things).

I want to make 3 things:

1. Connect with a flash (not web) application to a local mysql database.
2. Connect with a falsh (not web) application to a remote mysql database.
3. Connect with a flash (web) application with a remote mysql database.

All of this can be done without any problem, however:
1 and 2 can be done (WITHOUT using a webserver) using for example this:

http://code.google.com/p/assql/

3 can be done using also the above one as far as I understand.

Question are:

- if you can connect with socket wit mysql server, why use a web server (for example with php) to connect like a inter connectioN? why not connnect directly?
- I have done this a lot of times, using AMFPHP for example, but wouldn't be faster going directly?
- In the case of accessing local machine, it will be a more simple deploy application that only require the flash application + mysql server, not need to also instal a web server.
  Is this assumption correct?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What if the remote sql server does not allow remote connections ? then you need to have a webservice anyway. You can use also Java or C# to write a webservice for flex, it is not a must to be php. Plus having a webservice gives you more flexibility in data manipulation and increases security.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses.
I am opening however another question regarding the case where the flash application (Not air) is using a local database.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The necessity of separate layer of data access usually stems from the way people build applications, the layered architecture, the distribution of the workload etc. SQL server usually don't provide very robust API for user management, session management etc. so one would use an intermediate layer between the database and the client application so that that layer could handle the issues not related directly to storing the data. Security plays a significant role here too. There are other concerns as well, as, for example, some times you would like to close all access to the database for maintenance reasons, but if you don't have any intermediate layer to notify the user about your intention, you'd leave them wondering about whether your application is still alive. The data access layer can also do a lot of caching, actually saving your trips to the database, you would have to make from client (of course, the client can do that too, but ymmv).

However, in some simple cases, having an intermediate layer is an overhead. More yet, I'd say that if you can, do it without an intermediate layer - less code makes better programs, but all chances are for that you will find yourself needing that layer for one reason or another.

Answer (score 0):

Because connecting remotely over the internet poses huge huge huge security problems.  You should never deploy an application that connects over the internet to a database directly.  That's why AIR and Flex doesn't have remote Mysql Drivers because they should never be used except for building development type tools.  And, even if you did build a tool that could connect directly, any descent network admin is going to block access to the database from anywhere outside the DMZ and internal network.

First in order your your application to connect to the database the database port has to exposed to the world.  That means I won't have to hack your application to get your data.  I just need to hack your database, and I can cut you out of the problem entirely because you were stupid enough to leave your database port open to me.

Second most databases don't encrypt credentials or data traveling over the wire.  While most  databases support SSL connections most people don't turn it on because applications want super fast data access and they don't want to pay for SSL encryption overhead blah blah blah.  Furthermore, most applications sit in the DMZ and their database is behind a firewall so between the server and the database is unlikely something could be eavesdropping on their conversation.  However, if you connected directly from an AIR app to the database it would be very easy to insert myself in the middle and watch the traffic coming out of your database because your not using SSL.

There are a whole host of problems doing what you are suggesting around privacy and data integrity that you can't guarantee by allowing a RIA direct access to the database its using.

Then there are some smaller nagging issues like if you want to do modern features like publishing reports to a central server so users don't have to install your software to see them, sending out email, social features, web service integration, cloud storage, collaboration or real time messaging etc you don't get if you don't use a web application.  Middleware also gives you control over your database so you can pool connections to handle larger load.  Using a web application brings more to the table than just security.